# How to add image in Mapbox with turf.js grid

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox

I divide the map into squares with Mapbox-GL and trufjs and the grid is created.

I want to select some of these frames with the mouse and add pictures to the selected frames.

The image should be above the map and grid lines.

[image: Image 1.2]

I can add the image with the mapbox source. but for 300 small squares
http://mydomain.com/assets/myimage.png
Trying to download the image repeatedly with 300 requests from the address as in the example code below. and even if this process takes 1ms it is **horribly slow**.

```js
    for (let box in tile.area_boxes) {
      let bbx = tile.area_boxes[box];
      let bbox = [bbx.BoxOne, bbx.BoxTwo, bbx.BoxTree, bbx.BoxFour];
    
      const coordinates = [
        [bbox[2], bbox[3]],
        [bbox[0], bbox[3]],
        [bbox[0], bbox[1]],
        [bbox[2], bbox[1]],
      ];
    
      let s = Map.getSource("myImageSource" + bbx.uid);
      if (!s) {
        Map.addSource("myImageSource" + bbx.uid, {
          type: "image",
          url: strapi + "/.." + ads.icon.url,
          coordinates: coordinates,
        });
    
        Map.addLayer({
          id: "overlay" + bbx.uid,
          source: "myImageSource" + bbx.uid,
          type: "raster",
          paint: { "raster-opacity": 0.85 },
        });
      }
    }
```

[image: Image 1.1]

**I want to do**:

1 time download the picture. and copy hundreds of copies to the locations I specify.

Attention! : this is not a map marker. this is an image to be superimposed over a square. its size depends on the zoom ratio and should never extend beyond the frame.

Comment: Is it possible to save and reference these images locally on your machine / server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a GIS question but more of a general HTML/JS nature, but anyway, here's how you can solve this.

You can read each image that has to be repeated only once, draw it on the canvas and convert canvas to data-URL string with `.toDataURL` method. This URL string can then  be used as a source URL for your repeated images.

Function to convert image to data-URL could look something like this:

```
function toDataURL(src, callback, outputFormat) {
  let image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  image.onload = function () {
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
  };
  image.src = src;
}
```

Function is async and so returns result via callback function. Default image format is `image\png`.

You can then store all your image URL strings in some object from which can they later be retrieved by their ids. Code could look something like this (not tested):

```
var imageDataUrl = {};

function storeImage(imageUid) {
  var uid = imageUid;
  toDataUrl("myImageSource" + uid, function(dataUrl) {
    imageDataUrl[uid] = dataUrl;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.